# ¿Por qué no funciona el condicional al introducir un dato que no cumple con ninguna de las dos condiciones anteriores?

Tags: javascript, condiciones, algoritmos, else

Tengo un condicional muy simple pero veo que cuando ingreso 99 no salta el mensaje de "el número es menor a 100" del último else y no entiendo el por qué. Solo funciona con las dos primeras condiciones.

```
let dato1 =parseInt ( prompt ("ingresar numero"));

if (dato1 > 100) {
    console.log ("El numero que se ingreso es : "+dato1+" y es mayor a 100");
} else if (dato1 = 100) {
    console.log ("El numero que se ingreso es : "+dato1+" y es igual a 100");
} else {
    console.log ("El numero que se ingreso es : "+dato1+" y es menor a 100");
}
```

Comment: else if (dato1 == 100)? Te falta un =

Comment: } else if (dato1 = 100) {   <-- con esto lo que estás haciendo es igualar dato1 a 100, con lo cual nunca se va a dar el caso del else. Operadores de comparación para elementos iguales: == o ===.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como bien han mencionado @Vicent y @H.Díaz en los comentarios, tu error se encuentra en el símbolo de igual.

En un condicional if (y esto vale para casi todos los lenguajes), si deseas comparar dos valores, debes usar dos símbolos de igual. De lo contrario, asignas 100 a dato1. Por lo tanto, la forma correcta sería esta:

```
let dato1 =parseInt ( prompt ("ingresar numero"));

if (dato1 > 100) {
    console.log ("El numero que se ingreso es : "+dato1+" y es mayor a 100");
} else if (dato1 == 100) {
    console.log ("El numero que se ingreso es : "+dato1+" y es igual a 100");
} else {
    console.log ("El numero que se ingreso es : "+dato1+" y es menor a 100");
}
```

Avísanos si tienes cualquier otra duda, y no te preocupes: es un error muy común.